# VBA error 1004 occurs when accessing Names within events

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling, names

I cannot set (or read) a name in event-driven procedures.  This line of code fails only when within an event, with

> error 1004 "application-defined or object-defined error".

```
Names("infoLastSheet").Value = "TOC"
```

"InfoLastSheet" has Workbook scope.

Comment: Perhaps try using `ThisWorkbook.Names("infoLastSheet").Value = "TOC"`

Comment: I tried with `Workbook_SheetActivate` and `Worksheet_SelectionChange` but could not replicate the issue. Could you give more details? Surrounding code, for example.

Comment: Thanks Justyna, it worked.  Before the user navigates away from the Table of Contents by clicking a hyperlink, I wanted to record that that's where the user came from.  here is the working code



Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
ActiveWorkbook.Names("infoLastSheet").Value = "TOC"
End Sub